# AngularJS $scope in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I have the following situation, I use a jQuery preload plugin.

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('Preloader', function Preloader(Videos) {


        return {
            start: function() {

                $.html5Loader({
                    filesToLoad: Videos.query(),
                    onBeforeLoad: function() {},
                    onComplete: function() {
                      //$scope.loaded = done
                    },
                    onElementLoaded: function(obj, elm) {},
                    onUpdate: function(percentage) {
                      //$scope.precentage = precentage
                    }
                });

            }
        }

    });
```

I build a factory where I wrap the plugin.

In my controller I have something like:

```
angular.module('playlist')
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Preloader, Videos) {

        Preloader.start();
```

And on the HTML I have a loading screen which I want to hide with ng-if="!loaded".

Can someone explain me how to link the $scope.loaded from the factory to the $scope.loaded inside my controller?

Comment: suggest you put that code in a directive which already exposes scope.

Comment: `$scope` in Angular is always associated with an HTML view. Factories/services are not associated with any views, and therefore do not get a `$scope` injected into them like a controller would. Services/factories can have the `$rootScope` injected into them. You can put things on the `$rootScope` or better use a directive like suggested above to access a specific `$scope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directive is the right way to go in this case and not factory.
This way, you can expose the `loaded` variable using the directive `$scope`.

If you would like to use factory anyway, expose the `loaded` variable as a member of the factory so you can watch for changes in the controller.

**EDIT**

To call `start` you can use events or two-way binding (which is my favorite)

Comment: But how can I start the preload like I do now in my directive? Now I have         Preloader.start();

Comment: Sorry, can you detail a little bit more? If I make a directive and I use link function, the preload will start when the page is loaded?

Comment: the link function is called when the element is attached to the DOM

Comment: http://jsbin.com/turuwotuda/1/edit?html,js,output, I have problem I have this link: function(scope) {} but when I put {{percentage}} on my HTML its not updating

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rogemucini/edit?html,js,output Check this out, Its not all the code, but I the thing is that {{loaded}} or {{percentage}} are not being displayed in the HTML, and not updating

Comment: It doesn't find angular and jquery, add them as libraries

Comment: The problem its that the data from directive scope.loaded its not being disabled.